# Visualizando aniversariantes do mês atual no FullCalendar

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Tenho uma base de dados com uma data no campo `start`, gostaria de exibir somente os aniversariantes do mês corrente no `fullcalendar`, mas estou com duas dificuldades:

- selecionar somente os aniversariantes do mês corrente
- mostrar os aniversariantes no mês correspondente no ano atual do calendário, e não no ano original do campo.

Atualmente tenho este código:

```
<?php

//Database
$data = array();


$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "agenda");

mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM clientes";

if ($result = $link->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $obj->id,
            'title'=> $obj->title,
            'start'=> $obj->start
        );
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#clientes').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events : <?php echo json_encode($data);?>
        });

    });

</script>
```

E a exibição está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não consegui entender a ordenação anual a que se refere...

Comment: é pq ele pega o ano nessa data que vem do banco... só que eu tava querendo apenas o mês, eu to querendo fazer uma view para os aniversariantes do mês. @Magic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primeira parte do problema se resolve com a função `MONTH` do próprio MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE MONTH( start ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE );
```

- `MONTH()` retorna apenas o mês de uma data ( `DAY` e `YEAR` retornam o dia e o ano).
- `CURRENT_DATE` retorna sempre a data atual.

Depois, para exibir os dados como sendo aniversário, temos que trocar o ano original pelo ano corrente. Um dos jeitos mais simples é fazer a alteração no próprio SELECT também.

Aproveitando, vamos eliminar o `*` do `SELECT` e especificar exatamente o que queremos:

```
SELECT
       id,
       CONCAT_WS( '-', YEAR( CURRENT_DATE ), MONTH( start ), DAY( start ) ) AS aniversario,
       titulo
FROM 
       clientes
WHERE
       MONTH( start ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE );
```

Assim, uma data como `2010-05-30` será retornada como `2016-05-30`, aparecendo no mês atual no `fullcalendar`.

Como recriamos a data usando funções, o `AS aniversário` serviu para darmos um nome na coluna retornada, então finalizamos com este ajuste:

```
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $obj->id,
        'title'=> $obj->title,
        'start'=> $obj->aniversario
    );
}
```

Se em algum momento quiser exibir o calendário do ano todo, basta tirar o `WHERE MONTH( start ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE )` da *query*, pois o `CONCAT` aliado ao `fullcalendar` já vai separar tudo por mês naturalmente.

<sub>Esta resposta aproveitou algumas boas sugestões do @Randrade, na [sala de chat do SOpt](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32420850#32420850)</sub>